# Ruby Regex to validate format xxx-####

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to validate input evidence number as per following formats in my model.

```
XXX-### 
XXX-#### 
XXX-##### 
XXX-######
XXXX-#####
```

XXXX are alphabets and #### are numeric digits

I have following in my model code.

```
validates_format_of :evidence_number, :with=> /[A-Z a-z]{3}-\d{3,6}/
```

It only works for digits less than 3 ie it works for XXX-12 but does not work for digits more than 6 i.e. it does not work for XXX-1234567

Comment: If you want a minimum of 3 characters you'd use `{3,}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the `^` starts and `$` ends with.

```
validates_format_of :evidence_number, :with=> /^[A-Za-z]{3,4}-\d{3,6}$/
```

Use `mu is too short`'s answer though.

Comment: what about this case: XXXX-#####

Comment: http://rubular.com/r/7RethESKeC, you can use the similar `{min, max}` for the letters as well.

Comment: What happens when `evidence_number` is `"wrong\nXXX-999\nanchors"`?

Comment: That's because rubular isn't evaluating the sample data in a double-quoted string context so `\n` is a literal `\n` rather than a newline.

Comment: Yeah, lol I realized that a bit late. I'm a little slow today.

Comment: This doesn't match the example given above:XXXX-#####

Answer (score 3):

You should be using the `\A` (beginning of string) and `\z` (end of string) anchors, not `^` (beginning of line) and `$` (end of line):

```
validates_format_of :evidence_number, :with=> /\A[A-Z a-z]{3}-\d{3,6}\z/
```

A simple example will illustrate the difference:

```
>> "wrong\nXXX-999\nanchors" =~ /^[A-Z a-z]{3}-\d{3,6}$/
=> 6
>> "wrong\nXXX-999\nanchors" =~ /\A[A-Z a-z]{3}-\d{3,6}\z/
=> nil
>> "XXX-999" =~ /^[A-Z a-z]{3}-\d{3,6}$/
=> 0
>> "XXX-999" =~ /\A[A-Z a-z]{3}-\d{3,6}\z/
=> 0
```

You almost always want to use `\A` and `\z` instead of `^` and `$` in Ruby.

If you need "at least three digits" after the hyphen then you want:

```
/\A[A-z a-z]{3}-\d{3,}\z/
```

And [Kenny Grant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12186073/479863) is right, that space in the character class looks odd.

Comment: If the phone number is in a text area, maybe, but that seems unlikely.

Comment: @DaveNewton: The unlikely happens every day in software. SQL injection is unlikely if the data is coming from a form but we still take sensible precautions to prevent unexpected data from making a mess.

Answer (score 1):

You might be best to set up some test code, and test the regex separately (or ideally set up a unit test and test it that way).

```
invalid   = %w[777-2345 ABCD-12 ABCD-12345678 AB-12345678 ABC-1234567]
valid     = %w[ABC-12345 ABCD-123 ABCD-1234 ABCD-12345 ABCD-123456]

def validate codes,regex
  codes.each do |code|
  if code =~ regex
     puts "Valid code #{code}" 
   else
     puts "Invalid code #{code}"
   end
 end
end
```

When testing the above with your regex, some problems emerge. From your description, I don't understand why your regex includes a space as an allowed character - for codes this seems unlikely to be a valid code. So you might be better with something like this:

```
/\A[A-Za-z]{3,4}-\d{3,6}\z/
```

Which limits the match to a full string, and limits the first match to 3 or 4 alpha characters, and the final match to 3-6 numbers. This is assuming the #### is not a mistake in your examples:

```
puts "\n\nUSING NEW REGEX"
puts "Validating valid codes"
validate valid,/\A[A-Za-z]{3,4}-\d{3,6}\z/
puts "\nValidating INVALID codes"
validate invalid,/\A[A-Za-z]{3,4}-\d{3,6}\z/
```

Answer (score 0):

Add beginning- and end-of-string regex chars:

```
validates_format_of :evidence_number, :with=> /^[A-Z a-z]{3}-\d{3,6}$/

ruby-1.9.3-p125 :000 > "ABC-1234567".match /[A-Z a-z]{3}-\d{3,6}/
 => #<MatchData "ABC-123456"> 
ruby-1.9.3-p125 :001 > "ABC-1234567".match /^[A-Z a-z]{3}-\d{3,6}$/
 => nil
```